# Bot receiver listen only to itself

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i have problem with createReceiver. I have code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  // Voice only works in guilds, if the message does not come from a guild,
  // we ignore it
  if (!message.guild) return;

  if (message.content === '/q') {
    // Only try to join the sender's voice channel if they are in one themselves

    const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;

    if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
      message.member.voiceChannel.join()
        .then(connection => { // Connection is an instance of VoiceConnection
            connection.on('error', console.error);

            // const dispatcher = connection.playFile('C:/Denwer/ddradio/lyubov.mp3');

            connection.on('speaking', (user, speaking) => {
                if(speaking) {
                    const receiver = connection.createReceiver();
                    const stream = receiver.createPCMStream(user);

                    stream.on('data', chunk => {
                        console.log(chunk.length);
                    });
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(console.log);
    } else {
      message.reply('');
    }
  }
})
```

`console.log(chunk.length);` working only when playing music, those. only when the bot speaking. He does not hear other members. Please tell me what the problem is

Comment: He will send pcm only when he speaks himself, but does not transmit pcm, when other users speak, while speaking, speaking, it also works for users.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, I don't know how to completely fix it forever, but if you play a short audio file, like a beep, when the bot joins the channel, your code should work.